# Jekyll theme after forked to my account could not work

Tags: github, themes, jekyll

I forked a Jekyll theme named **Flexible Jekyll** to my account with a hope to change the theme of my Github website. My website should have the theme like this:  https://github.com/hadinh1306/stack-overflow/blob/master/Blog-should-look-like-this.JPG

However, on my site, it appears like this: https://github.com/hadinh1306/stack-overflow/blob/master/Blog-theme-problem.JPG

I made some changes:

-- `_config.yml`: Updated information for site title, author name, etc. There is nothing related to the theme setting.

-- `_posts`: The original `_posts` folder has some blog posts and a `.DS_Store` file. I deleted all of them, and added a new blog post of mine.

Did I do something wrong, or do I need to have a certain file/code in my repo for the theme to work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: The CSS are not loading, show us the code in `_layout/default.html` to make sure.

Comment: Did you put it in a /blog directory? The themes are mostly designed to work from the root. And I agree with Pradana: this is a CSS (only) problem. The path to your CSS is probably not correct.